# Predefine a nested dictionary to all None in __init__ method

Tags: python

I'd like to use a nested dictionary that is set to a default value, say None. But I'm having trouble initializing these in the init function. Here is a snippet -

```
class foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        # Define a dictionary
        self["car"] = None
        self["plane"] = { self["plane"]["wing"] : None, self["plane"]["fuselage"] : None }
```

Intention here is that `plane` is another dictionary inside `foo` and it's keys must be initialized to None. How do I get it right? With the above snippet I get an error:

```
>>> df = foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in __init__
KeyError: 'plane'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just write:

```py
class foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        # Define a dictionary
        self["car"] = None
        self["plane"] = {"wing": None, "fuselage": None}
```

or alternatively:

```py
class foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        # Define a dictionary
        self["car"] = None
        self["plane"] = {}
        self["plane"]["wing"] = None
        self["plane"]["fuselage"] = None
```

If you want to get nested dictionaries but don't really need a subclass of `dict` you can just create nested dicts like this:

```py
my_dict = {"car": None, "plane": {"wing": None, "fuselage": None}}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to make a class so it could be imported into other files as a pre-known dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily via the [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) class method:

```
class Foo(dict):
    def __init__(self):
        # Define a dictionary
        self["car"] = None
        self["plane"] = dict.fromkeys(("wing", "fuselage"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dict.fromkeys(["wing", "fuselage"])
{'wing': None, 'fuselage': None}
```